# windows forms local database

Tags: .net, winforms, mdf, local-database

Created a very simple windows forms app using .net, and connected to a local MDF file for basic CRUD operations. This is all working as expected on my PC.

I have passed this app to a friend to test, (a non development machine) and he is having issues running it..

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or 
instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL 
Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the 
instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow 
remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - 
Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL
Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database 
Runtime feature is enabled.) --->
```

Am i right in thinking that they will need to also install SQL express to get this to work?

Comment: You should have used a portable database for this rather than a SQL Server as your friend is unable to access the SQL server instance you're running.

Comment: Provided your connection string is configurable and not hard coded, SQL Express can assist. You'll have to run a script to recreate the database, restore a backed up copy, detach attach etc... to get the database and change the connection string to match your friend's test machine